# UDDI config error: input string was not in correct format

Tags: uddi

I'm trying to install UDDI 3 (from the biztalk media) and I'm getting an error while configuring the web services: input string was not in a correct format.

I've used the same method to install on another server and it worked fine, but it's not working now.

Does anyone know what the problem is, or at least where should I check?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the xml requests. Also, it may be worthwhile to download Apache jUDDI and try the same requests with that. (Note that the default install requires auth tokens and is not HTTP NTLM/BASIC based authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I, sadly, can't understand half of what you mentioned. I'm trying to install UDDI on Windows 2008 R2. I don't know where to get the XML requests from. After checking the log file I found out that the actual error message is "Message: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: MS UDDI asks for a few things when installing. Try removing spaces and any special symbols from anything you've entered. It's possible it's a file system related thing